# Unity Screen Resolution after build .exe Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, exe, resolution

So I'm trying to make a game in Unity, and everything is fine, the screen resolution on the Game and Scene view are perfect and well adjusted for every aspect ratio, but after I build the game, and execute the built version of it, the resolution goes crazy.. Before executing the game, there's an option to change resolution but all of them won't work!

I only see 1/4 of the game, it's like the game is being pushed down and to the right.

How can I fix this? Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: Since your screenshots failed can you simply describe the actual problem with words?

Comment: Wow, I highly dislike this system where you can't post images, just made no sense to me now.. Okay, when I execute the built version of the game, I only see 1/4 of the actual game, the rest goes black..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

All I had to do was add a main camera to the scene, I thought since I had the UI canvas I didn't need a camera but I was wrong.

Now it's all working perfectly.